# azure function activity in pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-functions, adfs

Call to provided Azure function 'HttpTrigger1' failed with status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'.

Comment: I am sorry, but what exactly do you expect of us by giving no context at all? Did you check the logs?

Answer (score 0):

> Call to provided Azure function 'HttpTrigger1' failed with
> status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function
> failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'.

You can get nothing from the server error.

The right way is to go to check the log files of azure function.

1, go to the kudu:

`https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

Click to folder`\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\function\yourtriggername`

Then you will find the log files:

[image]

You can find the details of the error in it.

In short, the internal problems of the function app cause server problems. If you want to know exactly where the problem occurred, you need to check the function log.